Equality test of two hyperbolic expressions
I am trying to compare two expressions to see whether they are equal using approximations:
$$\coth \left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right)+\frac{1}{2} \text{csch}^2\left(\frac{\pi }{4}\right),$$
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{256 k \coth (\pi  k)}{\pi ^2 \left(1-256 k^4\right)^2}+\frac{65536 k^5 \coth (\pi  k)}{\pi ^2 \left(1-256 k^4\right)^2}\right)+\frac{64}{\pi ^3}.$$
Mathematica says they match within 28 digits. Could it be done another way?
N[{Coth[Pi/4] + (1/2)*Csch[Pi/4]^2, 
   64/Pi^3 + Sum[(256*k*Coth[k*Pi])/((1 - 256*k^4)^2*Pi^2) + 
   (65536*k^5*Coth[k*Pi])/((1 - 256*k^4)^2*Pi^2), {k, 1, ∞}]}, {∞, 40}]


Please provide Mathematica code!

N[Coth[Pi/4] + 1/2 Csch[Pi/4]^2 - 64/Pi^3 -    NSum[(256 k (1 + 256 k^4) Coth[      k \[Pi]])/((1 - 256 k^4)^2 \[Pi]^2), {k, 1, Infinity},     Method -> {"EulerMaclaurin",       Method -> {"NIntegrate", "MaxRecursion" -> 10,         Method -> "DoubleExponential"}}, WorkingPrecision -> 60], 100] gives: 0.*10^-43 ?

As request by @UlrichNeumann , please show us the code text rather than $\LaTeX$. (You may want to read this BTW: https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1585/1871 ) The question will be reopened once it meets the standard of the site.

This is a math question, not a Mathematica question.There are formulas for summaions (e.g. Abel-Plana and with  residues ).

"Mathematica says they match within 28 digits. Could it be done another way?" Do you mean you expect an approach giving better precision for numerical verification?

As $\coth(\pi k)$ is very close to 1 (approaching it as $1+2e^{-2 \pi k}$ for $k\to\infty)$, it is numerically much more stable to sum the dominant component 1 separately from the rest, by writing $\coth(\pi k) = \left(1\right)+\left(\coth(\pi k)-1\right)$. The sum then becomes manageable to arbitrary precision.
Effectively, we rewrite the summand as
$$
\frac{256 k \coth (\pi  k)}{\pi ^2 \left(1-256 k^4\right)^2}+\frac{65536 k^5 \coth (\pi  k)}{\pi ^2 \left(1-256
   k^4\right)^2}
= \frac{256 k \left(256 k^4+1\right)}{\pi ^2 \left(1-256 k^4\right)^2} + \frac{256 k \left(256 k^4+1\right)}{\pi ^2 \left(1-256 k^4\right)^2}\left(\coth(\pi k)-1\right).
$$
First the component $(1)$ can be summed analytically to infinite precision,
a1 = 64/π^3 + Sum[(256 k (1 + 256 k^4))/((1 - 256 k^4)^2 π^2),
                  {k, 1, ∞}] // ToRadicals // FullSimplify
(*    (128 + π (16 - 16 Catalan - I PolyGamma[1, 1 - I/4] + I PolyGamma[1, 1 + I/4]))/(2 π^3)    *)

Then, the component $(\coth(\pi k)-1)$ to $d$ digits of precision: $\coth(\pi k)-1\approx 2 e^{-2 \pi  k}$ and we want these terms to be less than $10^{-d}$, so we use Solve[E^(-2 k π) == 10^(-d), k, Reals] to find that we need to sum roughly up to $k_{\text{max}}=d\ln10/(2\pi)$:
With[{d = 10^3},
  a2 = N[Sum[(256 k (1 + 256 k^4))/((1 - 256 k^4)^2 π^2) (Coth[k π] - 1), {k, Ceiling[d*Log[10]/(2 π)]}], d]]
(*    0.00038369149680482197420000118487465910950835903135209169226671463650...    *)

a = a1 + a2 // Re
(*    2.18748077115621861954967204476522167402966510757540894812897519265018...    *)

Compare to the analytic expression:
b = Coth[π/4] + 1/2 Csch[π/4]^2;
a - b
(*    0.*10^-1004    *)

You can easily extend this calculation to many more digits.

Nice solution (+1).  Why isn't it sufficient to define a2=N[Sum[(256 k (1 + 256 k^4))/((1 - 256 k^4)^2 \[Pi]^2) (Coth[       k \[Pi]] - 1), {k, 1, Infinity}], 50] without Ceiling part Ceiling[d*Log[10]/(2 \[Pi])] ? Thanks!

@UlrichNeumann because N[Sum[...]] is the same as calling NSum directly; and in my experience NSum is one of the worst functions in all of Mathematica: it is difficult (at least for me) to coax it into giving accurate answers and is usually far worse than what I can do with a bit of asymptotic analysis of the problem. For example: how would you get 1000 digits out of the method you suggest? Simply replacing your 50 by 1000 won't do the trick. Better to estimate how many terms we need, and then sum them up explicitly.

@Roman thanks for this incredibly instructive answer and the comment. +1 seems insufficient.

@Roman Thanks for your reply. Struggeled about Ceiling[d*Log[10]/(2 \[Pi])], got it now

@UlrichNeumann I've added a bit of explanation on this point now.

@Roman Thanks for the explanation
